# Illegal use of undefined type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, compiler-bug

Considering the code example shown below, is `decltype(h{}.t());` a legal expression? Which specific rule in the C++20 standard either allows or forbids this?

```
struct d;
struct h { static auto t() -> d; };

using a = decltype(h::t());             // all ok
using b = decltype(decltype(h{})::t()); // all ok
using c = decltype(h{}.t());            // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/36xYG113h)

---

The error message produced by MSVC:

```
<source>(6): error C2027: use of undefined type 'd'
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'd'
```

---

Having stumbled upon yet another bug with MSVC, I've actually discovered a workaround for MSVC's deviating behavior. By simply providing a user-defined defaulted default constructor for type `h`, MSVC no longer complains about `d` being undefined.

```
struct d;
struct h {
    static auto t() -> d;
    h() = default;
};
using c = decltype(h{}.t()); // all ok
```

However, the problem still seems to persist when *skipping* use of `h`'s constructor, like with the use of `std::declval` for example (as in: `decltype(std::declval<h>().t());`). Also, be aware that by providing a user-defined default constructor, even when defaulted, this will cause `h` to no longer be considered an aggregate type.

Comment: Does `std::declval<h>().t()` behave any different in MSVC?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, fails with the same error, it wants you to define `d`.

Comment: @Blindy This might be very useful in generic code. As a simple example consider a function that returns/uses a container size. A member function `size()` could be a static one for a compile-time-sized container and a non-static one if container size is determined at run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explicitly permitted for the type of a prvalue expression operand to `decltype` to be incomplete. Temporary materialization is exceptionally not applied in this circumstance, so that a destructor of `d` isn't necessary either (which would require `d` to be complete to lookup the destructor). So `d` doesn't need to be complete. For reference to the standard see [[dcl.type.decltype]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.type.decltype#2).

The function `t` may also be undefined, because use in a `decltype` operand is not use in a potentially-evaluated expression and therefore not an odr-use.

Constructing a `h` object with `h{}` also doesn't demand either `t` to be defined or `d` to be complete.

The standard even includes a very similar example (see link above).

So MSVC is wrong here.

Comment: It seems that in order to call `t` by using the member access operator `.`, `h` will have to be materialized, and this shouldn't be a problem since `h` is complete. If, for example, `h`'s destructor is marked as deleted, and when trying `decltype([]<typename T = h>() -> T {}().t());`, all compilers reject this as `h` has to be materialized which invokes its deleted destructor implicitly.

Comment: So, since `h` *can* be materialized in the provided example, the use of `t` shouldn't be different from any other type of declared but undefined function, which I think is best described in [`[dcl.type.decltype]/note-2`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.type.decltype#note-2): "*... a class type is not instantiated as a result of being the type of a function call ... so the usual reasons for requiring a complete type do not apply*".

Comment: "_all compilers reject this as h has to be materialized which invokes its deleted destructor implicitly_": A _temporary object of type `h`_ has to be materialized. A materialized temporary object is always destroyed at the end of the full-expression, which here is the whole `decltype` operand, so the destructor of `h` is used and therefore must not be deleted, yes.

Comment: @303 Yes, the part above the note is the normative equivalent that says that no materialization, and therefore no destructor invocation, happens for the `d` prvalue (which is the contentious part).

Comment: After doing some tests with `mutable` subojects of a `constexpr` variable, which led me to the discovery of (yet) another bug that seems to point to the root cause of MSVC's deviating behavior, I actually stumbled upon a rather surprising workaround for MSVC (refer to my original post).