# Members wrongly initialized in nested aggregate? (MSVC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, undefined-behavior

**Update: Since this appears to be a compiler bug, I've submitted a [report to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Incorrect-initialization-of-nested-aggre/10574742).**

The output of the following code surprises me. My expectation is that `Inner` would have `num1` initialized to 10 (as it is) and then `num2` would be initialized, copying `num1`'s value of 10. So the output would be `10 10`. Instead, I get `10 4`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Inner {
    uint64_t num1{10};
    uint64_t num2{num1};
};

struct Outer {
    uint64_t a{};
    Inner inner{};
};

Outer makeOuter() {
    return {.a = 4};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto outer = makeOuter();
    std::cout << outer.inner.num1 << " " << outer.inner.num2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`num2` appears to copy uninitialized memory (or from the wrong address?). It receives the value of `Outer`'s member `a`, whether that is made to be 4 or 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

The compiler is MSVC 19.37.32825.0. Compile for example by running `cl main.cpp /std:c++latest /EHsc /O2 /link /out:program.exe`.

With clang++ or g++, I get the expected result, `10 10`. Compiler bug or my misunderstanding?

The effects of some other changes:

- Adding a constructor `Inner() {}` to `Inner` -> output becomes `10 10`
- Changing `Inner inner{}` to `Inner inner{11, 12}` -> output becomes `11 12` (expected)
- Changing `Inner inner{}` to `Inner inner{11}` -> output becomes `11 4`
- Returning `{}` instead of `{.a = 4}` -> output becomes `10 10`
- Creating `Inner inner{}` directly in `main` and printing its members -> output becomes `10 10`

Comment: You should report a bug.

Comment: what , again this bug? Check similar thing with inheriting a class (VS2010 one), would it inherit initialization properly?

Comment: Clang 16 runs into the same problem when attempting: `constexpr auto outer = []{ return Outer{.a = 4}; }();`. The problem goes away when providing `Inner` with a user-defined defaulted default constructor, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074018/illegal-use-of-undefined-type) related post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a compiler bug.

`makeOuter()` is translated into

```asm
Outer makeOuter(void) PROC               ; makeOuter, COMDAT
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR __$ReturnAddress$[esp-4]
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], 4
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+4], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+8], 10           ; 0000000aH
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+12], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+16], 4  ; <-- HERE
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+20], 0
        ret     0
Outer makeOuter(void) ENDP               ; makeOuter
```

If it's changed like

```c++
Outer makeOuter() {
    return {.a = 4, .inner = {}};
}
```

then it's translated into

```asm
Outer makeOuter(void) PROC               ; makeOuter, COMDAT
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR __$ReturnAddress$[esp-4]
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], 4
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+4], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+8], 10           ; 0000000aH
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+12], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+16], 10                    ; 0000000aH
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax+20], 0
        ret     0
Outer makeOuter(void) ENDP               ; makeOuter
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vdb4Yv6n8